# Bool in swift - playgrounds

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, swift-playground

I'm Learning swift using playgrounds. Can I declare a bool and have it be only true or false so I can use it as a condition for a function?

Comment: Swift has a  `Bool` type, and `let b = true` defines a value of that type. I don't want to sound rude, but I would suggest to read "A Swift Tour" in the Swift reference which is available as eBook and at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html. – Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can declare a Boolean variable using "Bool" type annotation .  For  Example      
var boolean = false 
or 
var boolean =  Bool()

if you want to use in an if else condition . you can do like that

if boolean == true {

// Statements

}

Here , boolean is variable name .You can take any variable name.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Simply writing:

```
var boolean = true
```

will create a boolean named 'boolean' and will be equal to true.
You can change it's value to false by writing

```
boolean = false
```

later on. The boolean variable will be true or false, not at the same time. I don't wanna be rude but you should check simple variable types and learn from there. It's easier that way.

Comment: Yes, probably. But this is a very fundamental question and I suggest you to watch videos or read documentations about swift language first.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply!